# Android .NET MAUI Blazor App Freezes When Connecting Barcode Reader

Tags: android, .net, blazor, maui

I'm encountering an issue with my Android application developed using .NET MAUI and Blazor. The app freezes when I connect a Bluetooth or wired barcode reader to the Android device. Upon investigating the issue, I found the following logs:

```
[GED] ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 29, oppidx_max 29, oppidx_min 0
[GED] ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 29, oppidx_max 29, oppidx_min 0
[BLASTBufferQueue] [VRI[MainActivity]#0](f:0,a:1) destructor()
[BufferQueueConsumer] [VRI[MainActivity]#0(BLAST Consumer)0](id:43ca00000000,api:0,p:-1,c:17354) disconnect
[View] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@2a57615[MainActivity], callstack = 
[View] java.lang.Throwable
[View]  at com.mediatek.view.impl.ViewDebugManagerImpl.warningParentToNull(ViewDebugManagerImpl.java:179)
[View]  at android.view.View.assignParent(View.java:20814)
[View]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:5455)
[View]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:8884)
[View]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:8856)
[View]  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:500)
[View]  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:441)
[View]  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:206)
[View]  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5691)
[View]  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5976)
[View]  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5891)
[View]  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:71)
[View]  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
[View]  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
[View]  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
[View]  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2405)
[View]  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
[View]  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
[View]  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
[View]  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8144)
[View]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[View]  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:573)
[View]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1023)
[View] [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@2a57615[MainActivity]
[InputTransport] Destroy ARC handle: 0xb400007be1d34eb0
[libMEOW] meow new tls: 0xb400007dc18b14d0
[libMEOW] applied 0 plugin for [com.bluelotusx.blxpos].
[libMEOW] rebuild call chain: 0xb400007dc18a14c0
[libMEOW] meow delete tls: 0xb400007dc18b14d0
[DecorView] isCts, pkg: com.bluelotusx.blxpos
```

Does anyone have any idea of this error? Please help me to identify this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To future viewers of this question, there was an issue with MudBlazor UI library old version. Updating it to latest stabile 6.11.0 worked for me.